# How to disable button on other pc

Tags: vb.net

I have developed a Windows application using C# 4 and SQL Server 2008,

My application works very well.

This application is using by six users at the same time.

I want that, whoever click button first from these six users, the button on other 5 user's PC must be disable till the user finishes adding data.. then it must be enabled...

something..

btn.disable = true;

data saved

btn.disable = false;

so, it cant be duplicated..

Answer (score 0):

You need set a flag someone on your data to indicate that a record is being edited. Then when the user attempts to edit the same record it first checks to see if the edit flag is set and if so then reports "You can't edit this record because someone is already editing it".

Disabling a button automatically will probably be very inefficient as you will have to constantly check to see if a record is being edited.

That said it *could* be done using a timer to continually check the database.

Comment: Could you show me some code or exact idea, how can i get it done